# Ubuntu Tweak - "enhance system security by disabling desktop lock"?

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

Hope it's a typo, or I have misunderstood this. Going through ubuntu-tweak settings , I see the below.

My Question is "How can one enhance system security by **disabling the desktop lock**?" Isn't it contradictory?

[image: ubuntu-tweak screenshot]

Comment: I guess it's intended for cases where you don't want users to do these things (e.g. a public computer), but I agree, the wording could definitely be better.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the box for it does exactly what it says; it disables the lock screen.  I know a while back it was possible to restart the system from the lock screen, meaning if auto-login was enabled, it was possible to unlock the computer.  That has been fixed for some time though.